# jdbc WARNING messages on slave node

Tags: java, jdbc, activemq-classic

I have 4 broker configuration spread across two nodes. Each node hosts a 
master node and a slave node(whose master is on the other node)

Now since the master nodes have already acquired lock, I see following JDBC 
warnings in slave activemq.log: 
Is there a way to suppress these warnings?

-- `2018-03-29 19:28:57,847 | WARN  | Could not create JDBC tables; they could 
already exist. Failure was: CREATE INDEX ACTIVEMQ_ACKS_XIDX ON ACTIVEMQ_ACKS 
(XID) Message: ERROR: relation "activemq_acks_xidx" already exists SQLState: 
42P07 Vendor code: 0 | 
org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.DefaultJDBCAdapter | main 
2018-03-29 19:28:57,847 | WARN  | Could not create JDBC tables; they could 
already exist. Failure was: CREATE INDEX ACTIVEMQ_ACKS_XIDX ON ACTIVEMQ_ACKS 
(XID) Message: ERROR: relation "activemq_acks_xidx" already exists SQLState: 
42P07 Vendor code: 0 | 
org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.DefaultJDBCAdapter | main 
2018-03-29 19:28:57,848 | WARN  | Failure details: ERROR: relation 
"activemq_acks_xidx" already exists | 
org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | main 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "activemq_acks_xidx" 
already exists 
... 
2018-03-29 19:28:57,852 | WARN  | Could not create JDBC tables; they could 
already exist. Failure was: CREATE TABLE ACTIVEMQ_LOCK( ID BIGINT NOT NULL, 
TIME BIGINT, BROKER_NAME VARCHAR(250), PRIMARY KEY (ID) ) Message: ERROR: 
relation "activemq_lock" already exists SQLState: 42P07 Vendor code: 0 | 
org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.DefaultJDBCAdapter | main 
2018-03-29 19:28:57,852 | WARN  | Failure details: ERROR: relation 
"activemq_lock" already exists | 
org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | main 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "activemq_lock" already 
exists/ 
...`

Comment: post your jdbccode